# Integer bigger than long in java

Tags: biginteger

I'm wondering if anyone can help me, I've wanted to learn to code for a while and my friend suggested starting out with java since its robust and apparently relatively easy so I've bought a few books and I'm working through learning different features and elements etc. Then I stumbled on to project euler (www.projectile.net) and thought it'd be a really interesting way to learn some new things.

I'm on to the third challenge on there which is to write a program which finds the largest prime factor of '600851475143' which is of course outside of the range of the long primitive data type. I've written a solution which will work for any long integer but I'm unable to run it with a number this big.

My friend who's been helping me learn so far is currently abroad so I'm not able to ask him how to work an integer this big so if anyone could help me understand a solution I'd be very grateful.

I'm pretty literate when it comes to computing but my programming experience is limited so plain English help would be appreciated so I can get my head around it.

Thanks in advance,

Marc

Comment: 600851475143 fits in a long. Also, the Project Euler link in your question got autocorrected.

Comment: when i compile and run code
[code]

public class Euler3 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  long n = 600851475143;
  
  System.out.println("the prime factorisation of " + n +" is ");
  
  for (long i =2; i*i <= n; i++){
   while (n%i==0){
   System.out.println(i+" ");
   n=n/i;
   }
 }
  if (n > 1) System.out.println(n);
        else       System.out.println();
}
}
[/code]

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing an example like how I am using it under for loop to find factorial of any number

```
    BigInteger factorial = new BigInteger("1");
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
       factorial = factorial.multiply(new BigInteger(i + ""));
   }
   return factorial.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

One, '600851475143' fits in a `long`. You should be fine. However you need to mind overflows from arithmetic operations that exceed that value, e.g. if you have a step that goes `while (n*n < 600851475143)` then at some point `n * n` will be bigger - it's your job to make sure it doesn't overflow. That being said, the max long in Java is 2^63-1...   you really should be fine.

Two, you can use `BigInteger` for problems with numbers of this size.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The literal 600851475143 of type int is out of range 

 at Euler3.main(Euler3.java:5)

is the error i get when i compile my code

Comment: solved it @djechlin thank you very much for the subtle hint. my code now runs and find the answer. thanks!